# Can't get a global variable on http request function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

it should be an easy one but I am stuck.
I would like to return the result of a function as a global variable. Here I have my function clearbit() for which I created the global variable clearbit_role.

But I can't alert this variable outside of the function... Any clue anyone?
Thanks!

EDIT: Added a fiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/luron01/sJ8Eu/9/

```
var  clearbit_role ;
function clearbit (web){
  var url = "https://prospector.clearbit.com/v1/people/search?domain=clearbit.com&seniorities[]=executive&seniorities[]=manager&limit=1";
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText.replace('[','').replace(']',''));
        var clearbit_fullname = response.name.fullName;
        clearbit_role = response.role;
        clearbit_role='test'

    } 
    } 
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer sk_605e7e64cbb1ebcca9e28b8a97d23f22")
  request.send();
}
clearbit()
alert(clearbit_role)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's *asynchronous* so `alert(clearbit_role)` is called before execution completes.  Do your work in `onreadystatechange`

Comment: add console.log(response.role) after clearbit_role = response.role; to see if the response.role is undefined

Comment: indeed works when working in the onreadystatechange but I need to return clearbit_role to another function.

Comment: So call that function in `onreadystatechange`. Synchronous calls are depreciated, you need to model your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create the variable clearbit_role outside of the function

```
 var  clearbit_role ;
   function clearbit (web){
  var url = "myurl";
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText.replace('[','').replace(']',''));
        var clearbit_fullname = response.name.fullName;
        clearbit_role = response.role;
    } 
    } 
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer sk_1be5451252ba4e31518e9b")
  request.send();
}
clearbit()

alert(clearbit_role)
```

Comment: No this is not the problem. you don't need to do that. very simple code as an example https://jsfiddle.net/op92cf1o/

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

is NOT in scoping, the `clearbit_role` variable is already  a global variable. But the problem is `clearbit` function is take a time to make the http request.

so the `alert` function run before the `clearbit_role` variable declaration.

**Solution**

use a function to run after AJAX request done.

```js
function clearbit (web){
      var url = "myurl";
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText.replace('[','').replace(']',''));
            var clearbit_fullname = response.name.fullName;
            clearbit_role = response.role;
            someFunctionThatRunAfterAjaxDone(clearbit_role);
        } 
        } 
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer sk_1be5451252ba4e31518e9b")
      request.send();
    }
    clearbit()
// But all code you want to fun after AJAX done inside this function
function someFunctionThatRunAfterAjaxDone(clearbit_role) {
    alert(clearbit_role)
}
```